# Qt C++ minimize and maximize window

Tags: c++, qt

I create main window by using class QWidget and setup window flag to Qt::CustomizeWindowHint (to disable title bar). But than I found problem - when I click on my program button on Windows taskbar - program won't minimize and maximize. What can I do to remove this problem? I use Windows 7. Sorry 4 my bad english.

Answer (score 16):

That's the feature of Qt::CustomizeWindowHint.When use this windows flag,you can hardly control the window.What you can try is adding two buttons to your window and connect them to **showMaximized()** and **showMinimized()**.Then you can maximize or minimize the window by clicking the buttons.

Comment: thanks for answer. I create buttons (minimize and maximize) in my program, all work fine. But I still can't minimize program window by click on taskbar button. Can I remove title bar from window, but not discard minimize functional?

Comment: The window flags you use just disable the mouse event,which means if you clicke your window,Windows just let it 'pass through' instead of 'hit' the window.If you wanna a  try, I think you have to use Qt::FramelessWindowHint and re-implement your own mouse event function.This article may help you: [link]http://blog.csdn.net/yiyaaixuexi/article/details/6362865 @Ramix

Answer (score 6):

This answer is a while ago but I faced the same challenge now and could find a solution. Maybe its helpfull for someone else. As proposed before one should specify `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` instead of `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint`. This also hides the title and border of the window. To still have the minimize/maximize feature I additionaly specified `Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint`, `Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint` and `Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint`. That's it!