# Qt - minimizing and maximizing app without standard titlebar buttons

Tags: c++, qt, minimize, qmainwindow

I have a Qt application where there is only one widget which is not a `MainWindow`, just a `QLabel`. It has not title bar (obtained through `setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint)`), thus the standard minimize and maximize buttons are not available. But there is a sidebar at the widget's side where we provide a minimize button that should behave as the standard minimize button.

How do I do it?

I tried the solutions at [Minimizing a Qt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599334/minimizing-a-qt-application) and [Qt C++ minimize and maximize window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271501/qt-c-minimize-and-maximize-window). Neither works. I can hide the app of course, on clicking the minimize button. Problem is, how to restore it through standard mechanisms?

Scenarios:

1. On Mac, the dock icon is clicked. Thankfully, OS X native APIs can give me a notification when dock icon is clicked, so based on that, I can unhide the widget and make it active.
2. On Mac, the app icon is double clicked in `/Applications`, or clicked in `Launchpad`. How do I get a notification for this? The code doesn't even come to the `main.cpp` that I can unhide it from there if it is hidden.
3. On Windows, the application icon in the taskbar is clicked (the app does not have a tray icon). How do I get notification for that and unhide it?
4. On Windows, the app icon is double clicked either in Program Files, or may be a desktop shortcut icon. How do I get notification for this to unhide it?

If this aproach is not correct, how do I show and hide the app as per standard behavior on both Mac and Windows?

Platform - Qt 5.3.1, 32 bit.

Comment: you can try to `saveGeometry` and `saveState` before accepting the minimize and then a `restoreGeometry` and `restoreState` http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/restoring-geometry.html

Comment: Can you give a sample code, or a minimal working example?

Comment: In principle it something happen it should be catch by the `event(QEvent *ev)` so by re-implementing in your `QLabel` this method, you should be able to see what append and which event is by checking the `ev->type()` value.

Comment: Yes, the question is how to minimize it (not close it), and how to restore it under multiple scenarios I have stated in question. I am still not getting you. A small sample code would be nice..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an answer, but it might help sorting out which events are triggered (points 1,2 and 3).

```
#include <QApplication>

class newapp : public QApplication {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    newapp( int &argc, char **argv ) : QApplication(argc, argv) {}

protected:
    bool event(QEvent *ev) {
        std::cerr << "APPLICATION EVENT " << ev->type() << std::endl;
        return QApplication::event(ev);
    }
};
```

and in your `main.cc` you will have

```
newapp myapp(argc,argv);
```

instead of

```
QApplication myapp(argc,argv)
```

Once you identify the events triggered, you're almost done: you need to tell to you newapp to restore the size of the `Qlabel` (there are tons of ways to do this, so provide your implementation and you might get more focused help)

For point 4, it's something else due to the different behavior between OSes as in Windows double clicking for the second time an app, will launch another instance of the application (on OSx it will raise the first opened app). You might find something that suit you in this project [HERE](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtsingleapplication)

Comment: Thanks Bibi. Some pointers will be helpful, how does this help 1,2 and 3? The code does not even coming to `main.cpp` in these 3 cases, how will it come to the `event` method on clicking the icon in Launchpad?

Comment: Well it's because `newapp` is a `QApplication` and it receives events from the desktop (here is the list: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#Type-enum). Then its up to `newapp` to handle it (i.e. hide or show the `QLabel`)

Comment: What event type should I look for in my case, i.e when the app icon is double clicked in in Applications or clicked in Launchpad?

Comment: Well, the fact is that there are tons (as you can see in the link above). The code I posted is to find out which one is which. Once you've detemined this, you can implement the reaction of the application to such a signal. Please post some code of yours so that we can find quickly an answer. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Okay. I am trying with `QEvent::ApplicationActivate`. Till now it is working in Mac, detecting both dock icon click as well as Launchpad/Applications click. I will try it on Windows.